# Drupal Commerce default amount before adding a product

Tags: hooks, rules, commerce

I want that the Drupal Commerce module checkout by default starts with one specific product , whether you choose another product or not.

Is this possible to achieve this by building a rule? Which rule do I need to build?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to add product to the cart if it's empty or overwrite the default commerce checkout or what are you aiming for?

Comment: I think he just wants to add an item to the cart on each purchase, right?

Comment: I want to overwrite the default commerce checkout to be by default with 1 product. When clicing this url "/checkout" You will see that you have this 1 product. Thanks.

Comment: I want that the commerce checkout will start with 1 specific product. Whether you choose another product or not.

Comment: As googletorp is one of the committers for the module, I will leave the word to him, about the question making sense, or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but I doubt that this is possible with rules.

What you want is a custom checkout flow. Either this can be done by altering the checkout flow provided by Commerce, or disable it completely and write your own.

Either way you will need to write your own code to create this custom checkout experience, and this is beyond what Rules is capable of.